# UITextView attributes inspector not showing full set of attributes

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios7, xcode5

I have two Macs, both with the latest OS and Xcode versions. We're developing for iOS7.

On one Mac, everything seems OK. On the other, when I drop a UITextField onto a View Controller scene, the attributes inspector shows only a small subset of the attributes available.

I would expect to see something similar to the UITextView attributes but instead I see only this:

[image: shorter than usual attributes set for UIText]

Have I done something wrong here or is this a bug? I seem to remember having edited attributes on a UITextField that I added earlier to another scene (font, text size, etc) but these are not available now.

Answer (score 0):

I made a stupid mistake and I guess that someone else could do the same. I must have inadvertently clicked on the "Text Field" label at the top of the attributes panel and then scrolled up, missing it completely.

[image: Text Field collapsing header on attributes pane]

Doh!